# Why does my android project show dead?

Tags: android-studio

Android studio project shows dead in the Android monitor while my project is running perfectly in device and emulator. i have cleaned and rebuild the project also

Answer (score 0):

Tools-> Android- >Enable ADB integration   cick here in androoid studio to see logcat